# Cookies seen by everyone

Tags: php

Ok, so I want to store some user options in $_COOKIES after form submit.
My code is this:

```
    $reason=array_values(array_filter($_POST['reasontext']));
    $str=implode('|',$reason);

    if(!isset($_COOKIE['reason'])){
         setcookie('reason',$str,time()+86400*30*12);
    }elseif(isset($_COOKIE['reason2'])){
         setcookie("reason", "", time()-3600);
         setcookie("reason",$_COOKIE['reason2'],time()+86400*30*12);
         setcookie('reason2', "", time()-3600);
    }else{
         setcookie("reason", "", time()-3600);
         setcookie('reason',$str,time()+86400*30*12);
    }
```

Basically, for an array of let`s say: '1'=>'Test1', '2'=>'Test2', '3'=>'Test3'

The select tool should have had 3 options different for each user, depending on what the user submited as $_POST['reasontext'].

Well this isn`t so, **each user can clearly see what the other one has submited and stored in the cookie which should have been Personal**.

What I want is that each cookie 'reason' to be stored on each users computer and from there to load the different user-customised options.

Any tips?

Thanks in advance for the heads up :)

Comment: Cookies aren't shared in between users. I'm fairly sure there must be some other reason why you're seeing identical values. Are you 10000% sure you submitted different `reason` s?

Comment: Let's put it this way, istead of $_POST['reasontext'] I had an array with the following test values:1=>test1, 2=>test2, 3=>test3, well after testing it and seeing it work, I removed the array, replaced it with $_POST['reasontext'] and then made it live, guess what: All users reported the same issue, they saw test1, test2, test3 in their select dropdown. Why?

Comment: I'm not sure but I suspect an error somewhere in the script's workflow when overwriting the values. Maybe try again with different cookie names to make sure there are no previous values in the users' browsers

Comment: An error still wouldn't explain why users on different computers could still see my test values, I'm still looking into it.

Comment: if you hard-code test values into the script, then obviously every cookie is going to get filled with them, aren't they? What would be *really* odd is that if values entered by user A would show up for user B, but that's not the case, is it?

Comment: As I said above, I removed the test values from the script, but they still appeared. I don't exactly understand why, because as you can see I always deinitialise the cookies before assigning different values. see above my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want cookies to be private, you should:

1. Make your cookie consist of a unique ID and a signature to verify the ID.
2. Mark the cookie as secure, so it can only be transmitted via HTTPS.
3. Check the signature to validate the ID before using it.
4. Use the ID to lookup the data in your database.
5. Periodically reissue the ID and signing token, so it is hard to steal/forge.

If you want data to be stored just on the user's computer and not be transmitted to the server, then one of the various Storage interfaces would be good for that (localStorage, sessionStorage, etc.). However, you would set that in JavaScript rather than as a result of a POST, and the disadvantage to that mechanism is that the data would be specific to the browser on which it was set, whereas with the cookie solution, you could potentially restore the user's settings  when the user logs in.

Comment: The security issues adressed by you above, in my case, are null, because this is an intern utility seen only by the admins and above all, it's not sensitive data. But I think I'll just append the user's id at the end of the $_COOKIE's name.